# Design choice: Entity Framework vs Raw SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am writing a Silverlight application to process millions of records. Since the load on the server can be quite heavy, I intend to shift some of the processing to the client side. For example, if I needed to show complete information about a book and its author, I would want to JOIN the Book table and the Author table using AuthorID as the common key. Instead of performing the JOIN on the server side, I would retrieve Author table separately and Book table separately and join them on the client side using C# code and display them in a DataGrid.

The clients are in a controlled environment so there is a minimum guarantee of their performance. Since there are so many records and since there are no updations taking place in the client-side DataGrids, I would choose Raw SQL over Entity Framework. However, there is the issue of doing the client-side join. My question is, would Entity Framework help make the client-side join easier? Consider development time to not be a significant factor here.

Comment: Performing join on the client is no guarantee that it will reduce the load on the server.

Comment: Why would you join using the C# code. It's the database's job, and I bet it will be faster than any implementation you'd do using C#.

Comment: Help me understand: How would you even go about doing client-side joins using raw SQL?  Wouldn't that require a client-side DBMS?

Comment: @Michael: I think saying raw SQL he means "simple" SQL, T-SQL or whatever dialect of SQL language. Not ORM that hides all that under the hood.

Comment: @Clement: Consider storing a cache of the authors in a Dictionary with the key being the AuthorID. Consider displaying 100 records at a time in a paginated DataGrid. As the records are being displayed, the author information can be added to the DataGrid. It would be better to retrieve 100 books at a time and index author information onto the Dictionary rather than JOIN millions of books with their authors each time.

Comment: @Tigran: Understood, but I thought the question presumed that it would be executed *client side*.  How do you execute SQL client side without loading a client side DBMS?

Comment: My point is, if you've decided that you're going to do the join on the client in Silverlight, is raw SQL even an option?

Comment: @Michael: you are too precise. :) I PRESUME he is talking about executing join calculations in, let's say, DataSet locally and after send it to the server. Probabbly he has reasons for it.

Comment: @Anand: then use the `LIMIT` clause, and use many little SQL query instead of one return millions of books and author.

Comment: @Anand: If you want a solid answer here, it would probably help if you'd clarify the issue Tigran and I have been discussing.  When you say "Raw SQL" on the client, what do you mean?  Because if you actually mean you want to code "SELECT * FROM..." on the client side, that's going to be tough without a client side DBMS.  But if you're going to do, say, client side joins with a DataSet object, as Tigran says, it's an entirely different matter.

Comment: Based on your responses to answers and other comments here it sounds like you already know what you want to do and are just looking for others to reinforce your (IMHO, flawed) design decision.

Comment: @Michael: I meant the latter. Store one table as a DataTable on the client side, retrieve a part of the other from the server side and join them on the client side (using say LINQ).

Comment: @Yuck: I am certainly open to new ideas. The only thing I am interested in is distributing some part of the workload on to the client and also would like to know if the idea that I have been working on can achieve that or not.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, would Entity Framework help make the client-side join
>   easier?

It's a matter of who's developing the application. Using the entity framework definitely has it's advantages. It gives developers the ability to write T-SQL "like" syntax within a C# or other .NET environment, but it has the same efficiency of executing SQL through the SQL libraries that already exist in .NET.

So easier? Maybe. More efficient? I doubt it. Usually you want to perform JOINS and things of the sort within stored procedures on the server side, only because the database is usually stored on a different machine, so why have one machine serve the website AND do the data manipulation you need?

That's my view on the whole thing. I know some people are starting to see the need to NOT write stored procs with everything becoming so easy to do within .NET, but I still like them.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally agree with your choice to user raw SQL in this case, at least basing on what I read in your post. You need as "fast" access as you can, and fast being performance objective, is very your app dependent. So you can tune exactly what you want in place where you want.

I'm talking about even client side, where you want to do joins, considering that you wrote: 
"development time to not be a significant factor here".

So I'm personaly vote for Raw SQL.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are particularly designed to handle massive amount of data. Servers are *intended* to handle such scenarios. Sending so much data to the client would easily affect performance badly. It is better to filter the data in the server, and *then* send it to the client. Servers were designed for this exact purpose.

As for Raw SQL vs. Entity Framework - if you choose to filter the data in the server and you need to do special optimizations - go with raw SQL, as it is much less limited. Otherwise, go with Entity Framework.

Comment: The author database would be about 30 MB. The network being used is very high speed, so transferring 30 MB is no big deal. And storing 30 MB on the client is no biggie either. The only important thing is to keep the CPU time on the server for other processor intensive operations as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Entity Framework versus Raw SQL but have you considered using Microsoft's [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649551.aspx) with a [backing store cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648661.aspx)?

This will cache data locally - which sounds kind of like what you are you are after.